# Is there a way of having a fetch() request occur while a html page is loading?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website in which I need to have a fetch request occur while the page is loading, otherwise it slows things down later. Is there a way to do this, as what normally happens is that this request is triggered through a button push, but I'd like to have it occur as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is by itself async, so there is no problem in using it while page is loading. Just call it directly, like so

```
<script>fetch('link').then(response => {}).catch(error => {})</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add fetch inside your [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

```
window.onload = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.api').then(r=>r.json()).then(data => 
  {
    console.log(data);
    //use data
   });
};
```

Based on your use case you can use other [events](https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded) too